# Unable to open an installed signed apk to toshiba thrive

Tags: apk

I am unable to open an installed signed apk on toshiba thrive, i have already enabled the Unknown sources and modify on android manifest min skd to 11 kai target to 17 but nothing..any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apk downloaded to a computer via USB and transfer to a tablet (file manager hd tablet) and from there run apk
help?

Comment: please write these comments in comments..this is not an answer.